# Empty output file without any error or worning

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, datatables

I am trying to simply join two files but I am stuck as the out file is empty. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is my code to join two files:

```
WD <- read.csv("~my path")
setwd <- (WD)

library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

mydata1 <- read.csv("~mypath\\20200514_002.csv", header = TRUE)
df1<-data.frame(mydata1)
mydata2<-read.csv("~mypath\\iRT_A2_MassList_Model.csv", header=TRUE)
df2<-data.frame(mydata2)
```

Replace a string in a column

```
df1$Comment <- gsub('[(heavy)]', '', df1$Comment)
View(df1)
Joint_df <- merge(df1, df2, by= c("Comment"="Compound"))
```

I also used by.x "Comment", by.y "Compound"...but does not work neither

```
View(Joint_df)
```

The output here is empty

```
write.csv(Joint_df,"~mypath\\Joint.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: @revans: Thank you for your suggestion, but using what fixed = True in gsub, unfortunately did not fixed the problem. Where would you implement deput in the above script? Thank you!!!

Comment: #Exp

library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

m.z<-c(493.7683, 613.3168, 496.2867)
Start<-c(12.55, 16.00, 19.62)
End<-c(14.55, 18.00, 21.62)
Comment<-c("SSAAPPPPPR (heavy)","GISNEGQNASIK (heavy)","HVLTSIGEK (heavy)")
Compound<-c("SSAAPPPPPR","GISNEGQNASIK","HVLTSIGEK")
m.z_2<-c(493.7682, 613.3168,496.2867)
RT<-c(12.90, 15.17, 18.03)

df2 <-data.frame(Compound, m.z_2, RT)
df1 <-data.frame(m.z, Start, End, Comment)

df1$Comment<-gsub('[(heavy)]', ' ', df1$Comment, fixed = FALSE)
Joint_df<-merge(df1, df2, by.x = "Comment", by.y = "Compound", all = TRUE)
View(Joint_df)

Comment: Below is an example of the data I would like to join:
  
m.z <- c (493.7683, 613.3168, 496.2867)
Start <- c (12.55, 16.00, 19.62)
End <- c (14.55, 18.00, 21.62)
Comment <- c ("SSAAPPPPPR (heavy)", "GISNEGQNASIK (heavy)", "HVLTSIGEK (heavy)")
Compound <- c ("SSAAPPPPPR", "GISNEGQNASIK", "HVLTSIGEK")
m.z_2 <- c (493.7682, 613.3168, 496.2867)
RT<- c (12.90, 15.17, 18.03)

df2 <- data.frame (Compound, m.z_2, RT)
df1 <- data.frame (m.z, Start, End, Comment)